# YouTubeEmbededPlayer GWT HowTo stop videos?

Tags: java, api, gwt, youtube-api

I am trying to use the youtube video gwt api.

The youtube-player works but how can I stop videos? I didnt find a command for that...

I created my player following:

```
protected YouTubeEmbeddedPlayer _youTubeEmbeddedPlayer;
_youTubeEmbeddedPlayer = new YouTubeEmbeddedPlayer(youTubeVideoID);
```

That´s the YouTube Player:
https://code.google.com/p/gwt-youtube-api/wiki/EmbededPlayer

Answer (score 0):

By using  [YouTubePlayerWrapper](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-youtube-api/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/com/google/youtube/client/YouTubePlayer.java).

You can stop video by calling the method

```
youTubePlayerWrapper.stopVideo();
```

Comment: But how can I use it if I created a YouTubePlayer like this: `YouTubeEmbeddedPlayer _youTubeEmbeddedPlayer = new YouTubeEmbeddedPlayer (id); _youTubeEmbeddedPlayer.stopVideo()` doesn´t work.

Comment: have a look at this class http://code.google.com/p/gwt-youtube-api/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/com/google/youtube/client/YouTubePlayer.java

Comment: yes i looked it up, but i don´t know  how to use the `stopVideo()` command, because normally i would use it like `_youtTubeEmbeddedPlayer.stopVideo()`, but it doesn´t work so. Thanks for help!

Comment: Sorry cant push you furthur,I did'nt use it before.

Answer (score 0):

This answer may not resolve the problem mentioned with the same library. In fact I tried multiple different library with every library having some issues. So end up creating my own wrapper. I have made it public check it if you can use it https://github.com/pandurangpatil/gwt-youtube